# SQL Server DB Locks - select with nolock

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, locks

We have several views that call other views. If the parent view selects from the child view with NOLOCK but the child view is **missing** NOLOCKs could this cause a lock?

IE:

VIEW1:

```
    select * from view2 WITH (NOLOCK)
```

VIEW2:

```
    select * from hugetable
```

Would selecting from view1 effectively ignore the `NOLOCK` as this is missing in the definition of view2?

Comment: Even a query using `NOLOCK` uses locks. `NOLOCK` doesn't mean "It will create no locks". [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

> All lock hints are propagated to all the tables and views that are
>   accessed by the query plan, including tables and views referenced in a
>   view.

This is easy to test.

### Setup

```
CREATE DATABASE Testing

GO

ALTER DATABASE Testing SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT  OFF

GO

USE Testing 

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Demo(X int);

INSERT INTO dbo.Demo VALUES (1), (2), (3);

go

CREATE VIEW dbo.[Inner] AS 
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Demo

GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.[Outer] AS 
SELECT *
FROM dbo.[Inner]
WITH (NOLOCK)
```

### Connection 1 (leaves a transaction open taking a lock and an uncommitted row)

```
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO dbo.Demo VALUES (4);
```

### Connection 2

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.[Outer]
```

Returns

```
X
-----------
1
2
3
4
```

Showing the `NOLOCK` hint was propagated down and it read value `4` from the uncommitted transaction. (Selecting from `dbo.[Inner]` is blocked as expected)